# MongoDB slow query for specific collection only

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a database which has some collections one of the collections have more than 1.5k document and when I query in that collection my query only take about 1 second which I'm happy with, but I have another collection with only 97 documents and when I query this one sometime it took more than 20 seconds to get my results back this is was I'm asking for in both of collections

```
coll.find().limit(15).skip(35).sort({uploadDate: -1})
.then(r => {
     return r;
})
```

the 1.5k collection size is (4mb)
the 97 collection size which is the one i has problem with only (2.27mb)

Comment: Your date is way too low, Maybe having indexes may help you better but for `1.5k` or `97` docs queries shouldn't take more than 300 or 500ms even without indexes. Also in general you need to check with this order `coll.find().limit(15).skip(35).sort({uploadDate: -1})` !! If you're facing this issue from code then you might need to check network connectivity between server n DB.

Comment: my 1.5k has no problem and I use index for both of them, but what is wrong with the order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to query only selected(limited) fields which you must required to make query fast. Also you need to check about index, avoid then if not required.